# Verificar se todos os elementos são iguais

Tags: php, mysql

Estou recuperando do banco de dados todos os tickets vencidos, com a seguinte query

```
SELECT user,status,hash 
      FROM ticket 
      WHERE datepay < date_add(now(), interval -1 month) AND user = '119'
```

O resultado é como esperado, como abaixo. Lê-se `status:usuário`

> 0:118 0:119 0:119

Porém preciso verificar se todos os status são 1 (significa pago), se houver pelo menos um usuário com 0:119 já está inválido. Já tentei utilizar array_unique, porém ele vai vai verificar todos os usuários e não saberei qual não pagou tudo.

Comment: Não entendi. Essa saída `0:118 0:119 0:119` não corresponde a `SELECT user,status,hash`... Poderia esclarecer?

Comment: Essa saída é para explicar melhor a estrutura, no PHP eu faço um loop (foreach) e estruturei status:usuário só para explicar melhor. Basicamente se algum usuário tiver 0:usuário já é inválido, só é válido se todos forem 1:usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é tratar com `for`, a lógica é simples

```
Se user.status == 0 então diga "usuário pendente"; 
  parar;
senão
  "o usuário está em dias";
```

Na prática ficaria algo como isso, considerando que a váriavel `$ftc` seja o objeto da query (`fetchAll`):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($ftc); $i++){
  if($ftc[$i]["status"] == "0"){
    echo "O usuário {$ftc[$i]["user"]} ainda tem fatura pendente".PHP_EOL;
    break;
  }else{
    echo "O usuário {$ftc[$i]["user"]} pode ser liberado".PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Já que você disse que se pelo menos um ticket está pendente já não é válido, então não precisa verificar todos os elementos, apenas parar a iteração de X usuário e continuar para o próximo, recursivamente.

### Contras

Caso haja muitos usuários pendentes, a aplicação ficará lenta, levando um alto custo no desempenho do servidor.

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo :D, eu não conseguia bolar com uma lógica, mas desse jeito é simples e fácil, eu achei que break pararia ambos os usuários, caso um estivesse inadimplente. Obrigado.